# Parameter 'Blend' doesnt exist

Tags: unity, animation, animation-states

I want to animate my character, but i got this error: Parameter 'Blend' doesnt exist.

if i use 1d Blend Type it works fine no bug nothing.

[image]

But if i change the Blend type

[image]

in the animation panel working fine the animation but if i run the game i get this error: Parameter 'Blend' doesnt exist and my character is freeze in one position what can cause this problem ?

parameters

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the "parameters" section in your animator window? the Parameter 'X' doesn't exist is given when a parameter is not present inside the animator.

Comment: of course, i edited it :)!

Comment: no, you need to click on the Parameters tab(upper left side, near the "Layers" tab)

Comment: Upssz sry edit again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, at first blend type on the inspector just said "blend" so I adjusted the parameters on the inspector side to match with Animator.

[image]

[image]